PyQt5 pyqtsignal object has no attribute connect
I'm working on a PyQt5 application for a course and need to implement a pop-up menu that appears when I right-click on the screen. I attempted to implement it, but I'm encountering an error stating that the PyQtSignal object has no connect attribute. According to the documentation, there should be a connect attribute, so I'm not sure what's going wrong.
Here is the part of the code concerned:
import os,sys,json
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtGui,QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox

#from scene import Scene
from view import View

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,position=(0,0),dimension=(500,300)):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        #...
        self.view=View()
        self.scene=QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()  # Model
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

        #...

        self.create_actions()
        self.connect_actions()
        self.create_menus()






    # ...



    def connect_actions(self) :


        # This doesnt work
        #self.view.show_popup_menu.connect(self.show_popup_menu_slot)

        # ...

    
    def create_menus(self) :
        #...

        # Popup menu
        self.popupMenu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)
        popup_menu_style_pen = self.popupMenu.addMenu(QtGui.QIcon("Icons/tool_pen.png"), '&Pen')
        popup_menu_style_pen.addAction(self.action_style_pen_color)
        popup_menu_style_pen.addAction(self.action_style_pen_width)
        popup_menu_style_pen_line = popup_menu_style_pen.addMenu('&Line')
        popup_menu_style_pen_line.addAction(self.action_line_solidline)
        popup_menu_style_pen_line.addAction(self.action_line_dotline)
        popup_menu_style_pen_line.addAction(self.action_line_dashdotline)
        popup_menu_style_brush = self.popupMenu.addMenu(QtGui.QIcon("Icons/brush.png"), '&Brush')
        popup_menu_style_brush.addAction(self.action_style_brush_color)
        popup_menu_style_brush_fill = popup_menu_style_brush.addMenu(QtGui.QIcon("Icons/brush.png"), '&Fill')
        popup_menu_style_brush_fill.addAction(self.action_style_brush_Cross)
        popup_menu_style_brush_fill.addAction(self.action_style_brush_Solid)
        popup_menu_style_brush_fill.addAction(self.action_style_brush_Horizontal)
        popup_menu_style_brush_fill.addAction(self.action_style_brush_Vertical)
        popup_menu_style_brush_fill.addAction(self.action_style_brush_DiagCross)
        popup_menu_style_brush_fill.addAction(self.action_style_brush_None)


    def show_popup_menu_slot(self):
        self.popupMenu.exec_(QtGui.QCursor.pos())

The show_popupmenu is defined in the view constructor in an other file like this:
self.show_popup_menu = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
We have to build our project in those 2 files
I tried to look on the internet, i found stack overflow examples with PyQt4 but it doesnt work in my case

Don't make us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question and include the full error traceback message.

Signals must be defined at class level, they cannot be added to an instance.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.
